# Create auto generate sequence number column

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, column

How do I change the default "Title" column in SharePoint 2013 into a column which have sequence number generate automatically?

Example as below:

```
PO-15-2001

PO-15-2002

PO-15-2003
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for separate tables keeping track of a unique number, the ID value is unique.

But you can not use it in a calculated column directly so you need one Workflow to write the item ID to another column `myID`

You can then use a Calculated column

```
="PO-" & TEXT( [Created] , "yy" ) & "2" & TEXT( [MyID] , "000" )
```

If you really want this in your Title column you have to add this string building to your first Workflow and set the Title field

If you need more fancy stuff:

[Create unique number with ListItem [ID] and [Today] age in Calculated Column Formula](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/160426/create-unique-number-with-listitem-id-and-today-age-in-calculated-column-for/160447#160447)

Comment: Hi Danny.. How to do it without workflow?

Comment: You did not click the link to the fancy stuff then...

Comment: I did and tried but the ID part it keeps coming up as 0000

Comment: the command is as below
`="PO-"&TEXT(Created,"YY")&"-"&TEXT(ID,"0000")`

the result is `PO-15-0000` each time I add new item.

Comment: You are using [ID] , that is not what the posts tell you to do. What name did you give your second ID column?

Comment: I created a new column called [eID]. Set as calculated column `=[ID]`. Then followed `="PO-"&TEXT(Created,"YY")&"-"&TEXT(eID,"0000")`
Still the same results.

Comment: and how do you auto update the item? With the mentioned workflow or the javascript code in the Formula?

Comment: Can we use validation method? the user need to key in as `PO-15-####`
Can I know how we can do it?

Comment: Learn how to do Column Validations: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=column%20validation

Answer (score 0):

You will need a workflow.

Step 1 - create a table with 1 item to keep track of the unique number (200x) (can also record any other information needed as well here)

Step 2 - create the workflow that gets that item's value and sets the Title field to PO-15-[Number]. Update the current number in the other list by incrementing it by 1 (or any other logic you have).

Step 3 - Profit.

Conversely you can use the ID number of the item it's self although be aware you can not edit the ID.